# SQL Query to get data for specific columns using python

Tags: python

I have a table with 1000 columns and I have a list of 100 columns that I want to pull from that table.

I have tried

```
df = db.query("SELECT * FROM rpt_SalesHistoryMAST where GLPostDate>'2017-08-31' order by GLPostDate;")
```

but its getting all the data. Is there any way to pull only specific columns that I have in list?

Comment: What about `SELECT col1, col2, ..., col100 FROM ...` instead of `SELECT * ...`?

Comment: Did you post all the code? I don't see anything in the posted code that tries to incorporate a list of field names in the SQL.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string join() method is useful - assuming you have a list of 100 columns ready (and in the order layout you prefer

```
Cols100 = ['Col1', 'Col2', ... 'Col99', 'Col100']
Col100ForQuery = ', '.join(Cols100)
DBSQLQuery = "SELECT " + Col100ForQuery + " FROM rpt_SalesHistoryMAST where GLPostDate>'2017-08-31' order by GLPostDate;"
df = db.query(DBSQLQuery)
```